# ALTER current database without using its name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to run update script on current database (`ALTER DATABASE...`), but can't use implicit its name. Is possible to use some function to get current db name and use inside `ALTER DATABASE` (Sql Server 2005 and above) ? I tried use `db_name()`, but doesn't work.

`select db_name();` works

`ALTER DATABASE db_name() ...` doesn't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use something like

```
declare @dbname varchar(100)
set @dbname=quotename(db_name())
exec('alter database '+@dbname+' ...');
```

or.. even simpler

```
set @sql='alter database '+quotename(db_name())+' ...';
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: I think it is due to the operation on the same database, Here is something useful for you
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/11/sql-server-alter-database-dbname-set-single_user-with-rollback-immediate/

Comment: @Raj - when I first typed this in, I assumed that I could use the function db_name() in the expression, but it needs casting into a varchar first. I will edit this to reflect this.

Comment: @Rich - Cool buddy. We all something new all the time, don't we :)

Comment: @Rich, Thank You. First version works good for me. In second You forget `declare @sql varchar(100);`

Comment: Minor nit: use quotename() instead of putting brackets in yourself. People do funny things with identifiers (like put square brackets in the name)!

Comment: @BenThul yep, good point, added the quotename function to both solutions.

Comment: This question is tagged as "sql-server", but for future viewers interested in the mysql answer:  The database name can simply be omitted (eg. ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
).

Answer (score 68):

Actually something more like this is probably a little better if you're altering the current database:

`ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90`

Comment: This is the neatest answer, but note that this only works for SQL Server 2012 and up. The original question is tagged for SQL Server 2005. 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238834/alter-database-current-exception

Comment: @AdrianEdwards, true, but it's also the first hit when googling, `sql server alter database current database`. :)

Comment: In MySQL, the "CURRENT" can omitted if you are currently in that database - eg, `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @DBName sysname;
SET @DBName = (SELECT db_name());
DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000);
SET @SQL = 'ALTER DATABASE '+@DBName+' .......'
```

Raj