# MySQL alter current database

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a way to use an `ALTER TABLE` statement in MySQL, without having to explicitly use the currently selected (via `USE`) database.

Essentially, I am looking for the same thing as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275935/alter-current-database-without-using-its-name), but for MySQL instead of SQL-Server.

I already tried

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

But that returns

```
ERROR 3503 (42Y07): Database 'CURRENT' doesn't exist
```

So it seems like MySQL doesn't know the `CURRENT` keyword.

I also tried some variants of

```
ALTER DATABASE (SELECT DATABASE()) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

but I can't seem to get it to work with that either (it always complains about invalid syntax).
Note that I know, that the plain `SELECT DATABASE()` gives me the sought-after name of the current database - I just can't get it to do that within the `ALTER DATABASE` statement.

How would I achieve my goal within MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, it seems I was trying too hard. Turns out that the database name is optional in `ALTER DATABASE`. So a plain

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

is all that is needed.